# Is there an explicit formula for the derivative of the matrix minor?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, soft-question, determinant, matrix-calculus

Let $M_n$ be the vector space of real $n \times n$ real matrices.
Fixe $1 < k < n$, and let $I=(i_1,i_2, \dots, i_{k}),J=(j_1, \dots, j_{k})$ be multi-indices, i.e.
$1 \le i_1 < i_2 < \dots < i_{k} \le n $ and $1 \le j_1 < i_2 < \dots < j_{k} \le n $.

Let $M^I_J:M_n \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function which assigns every matrix its $(I,J)$ minor.

> **Question:** Is there an explicit formula for the gradient of $M^I_J$?

That is, given $A \in M_n$, what is $(\nabla M^I_J)(A)$?

---

For $k=n$, $M^I_J$ is the determinant, and $(\nabla \det)(A)=\Cof(A)$ is the [cofactor matrix of $A$.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula)

Is there an explicit generalization of Jacobi formula for minors of other degrees?

Comment: Shouldn't it be the cofactor matrix of that particular minor, blown up to size $n \times n$ by putting zeroes in all remaining cells?

Comment: Thanks, you are right of course. I was thinking too complicated for some reason, and missed this...

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $\mathbf{A}_{ij}$ the submatrix obtained by removing the ith row and the jth column of $\mathbf{A}$.

You are interested in differentiating the scalar-valued function
$\phi(\mathbf{A}) = \det(\mathbf{A}_{ij})$.
It holds
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{A}_{ij}} 
= \phi \cdot \mathbf{A}_{ij}^{-T}
$$
the other terms are null, for instance
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial A_{ij}} = 0
$$
It remains to reallocate these derivative terms (right side) at the right place...